# Design of rtf template for multiple data sets

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher, xml-publisher

I have a seeded datamodel with two datasets. Dataset D1 has field F1, Dataset D2 has field F2, F3, F4

Example Datamodel:

```
<dataQuery>
        <sqlStatement name="D1">
        <![CDATA[
SELECT F1 from table ABC
]]>
        </sqlStatement>
<sqlStatement name="D2">
        <![CDATA[
SELECT XYZ.F2,XYZ.F3,XYZ.F4 from table ABC,XYZ where some_conditions
]]>
        </sqlStatement>
</dataQuery>
```

In my RTF template, using the datamodel, I have to create one table with columns F1, F2, F3, F4

The table is grouped by D2 with fields F2, F3, F4. I now add a new column with F1 and point to F1 from D1. When I do that, F1 is null and is not corresponding to the remaining columns.

I can achieve whatever I want by modifying the query D2 by adding a new field ABC.F1 but I cannot modify the seeded data definition.

Appreciate if anyone could help me provide a solution where without modifying the data definition, achieve the functionality in the template.

Thanks

Comment: It's difficult for me to understand what you are trying to do. Can you give some more details? Maybe some example XML and some example expected output, and example current output?

Comment: Thank you for looking into my question. I have updated the question to be more clear. Please review!